# FP sorting function in scala explained

Tags: arrays, scala, sorting, functional-programming

I've started to learn FP with Scala with the book *"Functional Programming in Scala" (Chiusano & Bjarnason, Manning Publications, 2014)*

There's a exercise in which you have to implement a function which checks whether an Array is sorted according to a given comparison function (solution as provided by the authors):

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordering: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
@annotation.tailrec
 def go(n: Int): Boolean =
   if (n >= as.length - 1) true
   else if (ordering(as(n), as(n + 1))) false
   else go(n + 1)

 go(0)
}
```

When invoking this function e. g. like this:

```
isSorted(Array(1, 3, 5, 7), (x: Int, y: Int) => x > y) //evaluates to TRUE
```

I would expect it to be evaluated to **false** (not true) because the arr is not being sorted in descending order (7,5,3,1)

```
 //Array sorted in descending order ">" as sorting-operator
scala> List(10, 5, 8, 1, 7).sortWith(_ > _)
res2: List[Int] = List(10, 8, 7, 5, 1)
```

May anyone can explain the function as I just don't get it. A thoroughly explanation is much appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
else if (ordering(as(n), as(n + 1))) false
```

Given the predicate `x > y`, this will yield `false` for every value in the array, thus passing continuing to the `else` clause until `n >= as.length - 1` is reached, which will make the method (falsely) yield true.

We can negate the predicate inside `isSorted`:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordering: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
@annotation.tailrec
 def go(n: Int): Boolean =
   if (n >= as.length - 1) true
   else if (!ordering(as(n), as(n + 1))) false
   else go(n + 1)

 go(0)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> isSorted(Array(1, 3, 5, 7), (x: Int, y: Int) => x > y)
res4: Boolean = false
```